# django admin tabularinline limit foreign key choice fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am using django admin tabular-inline admin interface.

model.py

```
class Issues(TimeStampedModel):
    issue_owner = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, related_name='issue_owner')
    issue_no = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)

class IssueComments(TimeStampedModel):
    comment_owner = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, related_name='comment_owner')
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issues, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to use tabular-inline in admin

admin.py

```
class IssueCommentsAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IssueComments
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None,**kwargs):
        field = super(IssueCommentsAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'comment_owner':
            if request.user is not None:
                field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(username = request.user.username)
                if not field.queryset:
                    field.queryset = field.queryset.all()
            else:
                field.queryset = field.queryset.none()
        return field

class IssuesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Issues
    list_display = ('issue_no', 'title', 'owner_phone_number', 'status', 'issue_priority', 'classification')
    inlines = [ IssueCommentsAdmin ]

    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        context['adminform'].form.fields['assigned_to_user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
        return super(IssuesAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

i want to restrict the comment_owner to logged in user only in choice-field. I am able to do that also but issue i am facing here is for the comments whiche already have the comment_owner i want to keep that as it is.
Here comments which have comment_owner are not getting pre selected.

Comment: PLS show the error, thanks

Comment: Not getting any error but comment_owner is getting blank for which comment owner is already assigned.

Comment: r u sure about:
field.queryset.filter(username = request.user.username)
maybe:


qs = super(IssueCommentsAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
return qs.filter(issue_owner =request.user.id)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but, for anyone

You should create another Model Admin class in admin.py and give permissions for this object. I recommend you change your classnames.

```
class IssueCommentsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...

class IssueCommentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...

admin.site.register(IssueComments,IssueCommentsAdmin)
```

In this way, you can edit all data with get_queryset and field data with get_field_queryset.

regards!